# Eclipse (Android): When clicking 'Run'/'Debug' nothing happens

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have just installed (extracted) properly the ADT bundle for eclipse + android SDK and also set a new AVD which is currently working on my background and looks fine.

my problem is: once i create any app and click the **'Run'** or **'Debug'** button, nothing happens.
I don't see any 'launching : (nn%) ..' message at the bottom and the AVD is not effected at all - nothing happens!
I have no idea what is the problem but a while ago i installed this exactly same way and had seen this issue before. could anyone please advice me what to do?

Comment: run adb devices in the console and see if the device is found by the adb

Comment: Nickolaus could u please re-explain? i dont see any adb title in the console area.

Comment: go to android-sdks/platform-tools there you will find the adb located

Comment: I just run it, im sorry but im new with android development and have no idea what im looking for in the output of adb.exe

Comment: okay sorry for the newbish questions i think i have managed for now to solve this

Comment: if you are in the console and navigated to the platform-tools folder type "adb devices" following adb will output that none device is attached or it will show a list of devices

Comment: oh! okay i now see it is attached a device properly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

right click you project->run as -> run configuration, check whether launce default activity is selected, and in target tab check "always prompt to pick device"

Comment: sounds like a specific solution for every project i'll re-open, hm.. when hitting 'run configurations' and selecting 'android application' it creates a new configuration which is relevant to a specific project, is that what u meant?

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically for the currently selected project like the old ADT did?

Answer (score 2):

If the button works fine for the first time and doesn't work later, try this.

Open Devices view using `Window > Show View > Devices`.

Then, in Devices, under your emulator, find your application package name. Select it and press the red "STOP" button.

After this, the application should run properly.

Comment: I just downloaded the combined Eclipse/ADT app for mac (Build: v22.0.0-675183) and there is no Devices option under the Show View menu...

Comment: In v21.1.0-569685, it's the 4th in the list.

Comment: It's in Show View &gt; Other then.

Comment: Also, "Run" does nothing on non-Java files (except for `AndroidManifest.xml`).

Answer (score 1):

In the editor MainActivity.java file should be open/in focus.Then run your app. It should work fine.
Problem occurs when some other xml file is in focus in the editor eg.styles.xml etc.

Answer (score 0):

click the down arrow next to run button go to run configurations. select target on  the tab menu and check always prompt to pick device is selected

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the connected device is responding or if you are using emulator then make sure it's well configured, I had this problem, I changed the usb cable and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the phone: you have to activate the developper abilities of the phone.

On the phone with Jelly Bean (4.2) and newer versions of Android:
Go to "Settings" --> "About Phone" --> tap “Build Number” until you get a popup that you have become a developer (5 or 7 times, count down will decrease ). Then go to "Settings" --> "Developer" --> "USB debugging" and enable it.

Elder versions of Android on your phone: This is usually done from "Settings" --> "Applications" --> "Development" --> "USB debugging" and enable it.

That's it !

Perhaps you will have to reboot the phone (not sure about this).

Then, retry
"adb devices" on your computer console: your phone is on the list, and ready to use with android studio or else !

Good luck now !

Reference :
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android
here:
Connect device